# Return NULL in case expression : SQL server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have following case statement for check result set,

```
SELECT
    CASE
    WHEN EXISTS(
           select CE_Issuedate from t_Certificate
           where CE_CertID_pk = (select IT_certID_fk_ind from t_item
                                 where IT_rfileID_fk = '1482'
                                 group by IT_rfileID_fk) 
    ) 
    THEN  (select CE_Issuedate from t_Certificate
           where CE_CertID_pk = (select IT_certID_fk_ind from t_item
                                 where IT_rfileID_fk = '1482'
                                 group by IT_rfileID_fk)) 
    ELSE  NULL
    END AS 'CE_Issuedate';
```

I want to return NULL when no result in this select statement. I tried like this but I'm not sure this is correct. This query is working, but I think return string value when no result.

Following script return like this:

[image]

but i think actually it's want to be like this,

[image]

please help me. is this right ?

Comment: That's a case expression, not a case statement...

Comment: ok i re-corrected  @jarlh :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select max(CE_Issuedate)
from t_Certificate
where EXISTS (select * from t_item
              where IT_rfileID_fk = '1482'
                and CE_CertID_pk = IT_rfileID_fk)
```

If no row is found, MAX returns NULL. Otherwise that CE_Issuedate is returned.